# Send Email as Root *Before* User Login?

Tags: root, postfix

I'm not sure I'm on the right forum for this, but I found some hints in another thread that suggest the knowledge base might work out here.

I've got a startup script running as root (managed by Lingon X) on macOS X High Sierra (latest as of 22 December 2018); the script is intended to do two things; one, log the (approximate) startup/restart time to a local file (works fine); and send an email to an outside address *before* a user login (works only if run manually after login).

(Note: I have a second script that logs/emails on login/logout; that all works fine, but I need to know when a remote machine is restarted and then, most likely, is stalled at the user login screen.)

I have `/usr/lib/postfix/master` running as root; and I tried naming the notification script with an alpha scheme to (presumably?) launch after it; I further tried sleep options to allow time for postfix to launch and accept new jobs.

No such jobs ever execute, nor do they accumulate in `mailq`

I played with trying to check for and sending only if postfix is running; it confirms that postfix is indeed running, gives me a PID for the log, but still won't send or at least place in the queue.

What service am I missing that needs launching beforehand? Or is there a missing element to sending email as root without a user environment?

Thanks for any help; if I'm in the wrong place, let me know, please.

Comment: The process may be running, but that doesn't mean the service is ready. It could be that if you delay your notification script that will give enough time for postfix to initialize.

Comment: Your suggestion is appreciated; I mentioned in my post attempting to sleep the script -- by as much as 40 seconds -- with no apparent difference. The machine can fully boot to Desktop in under 30 seconds, and, if automatic login is enabled, it will send the login email well before that, but never will send the startup email, though it has root permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out in Sierra and above, if you enable `AbandonProcessGroup` in your root-enabled launch plist, it will send -- most of the time. If you want pure reliability, you will also have to add a script or function to`sudo postfix flush` within a few seconds of sending the email before the login window engages.